# How do I use RelatedField from Django Rest Framework when there is a reverse ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here are my models:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    id = [...]
    address = [...]

class Property_Value(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    amount = [...]
    last_updated = [...]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.last_updated, self.amount)
```

My serializer are:

```
class Property_ValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Property_Value
        fields = ('last_updated', 'amount')

class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    1) property_values = Property_ValueSerializer(source='property_value_set', many=True)
    2) property_values = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('id', 'address', 'property_values')
```

I would like to display a json like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "address": "123 Apple Lane",
        "property_values": [
            {
                "10/13/2016": "1709195.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I use option 1, I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "address": "123 Apple Lane",
        "property_values": [
            {
                "last_updated": "10/13/2016",
                "amount": "1709195.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I user option 2 (which is what was suggested by the Rest tutorial, I get an Attribution Error:

```
AttributeError at /api/property/
'Property' object has no attribute 'property_values'
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) which returns the `__unicode__` representation for the related fields. In your case `__unicode__` method already returns the value in the way you are expecting in serializer.

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_values = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('id', 'address', 'property_values')

class Property_Value(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_filed="property_values")
    amount = [...]
    last_updated = [...]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.last_updated, self.amount)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  I still get an attribution error that says Property object has no attribution 'property_value'.  RelatedField and StringRelated Field should work the same way right?

Comment: Just add `related_field` attribute to your Foreign key field. Then it should work. `id = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_field="property_values")`.

Comment: I added the related_name in the model and used this in the serializer: property_val = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)  But it says: 'AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.'

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please note your `related_field` value and serializer field name should match.